# Ionic 4 & Angular - <ion-input> model not updating after service subscription result

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, service, ionic4

I have a Google Maps map handled by my `Home` page. Inside I have a header, which it's in an independent component, let's call it `Header`. I want the user to set the map over a place by dragging it and my Header component to display the address (quite classic).

Both the `Header` component and the `Home` page (handling the map) are communicating by a service called the `AddressService`. This service just takes the coordinates from the map and translates it into an address with the `NativeGeocoder`. The `Header` has subscribed to any result of this service and then shows the address in an `<ion-input>`.

The problem is that somehow the **ion-input won't update**, even if printing the values return the good ones. Magically, when I press on the ion-input the good value shows up, but sometimes when a press a button on another component too (maybe when the google map is losing focus, already tried but forcing it doesn't refresh the ion-input).

Other problems of this kind I've seen on the internet seem to all occur in older versions of Ionic (or in beta ones).

Here's how the service is called by the `Home` page:

```
onMapWasDragged(params: any[]) {
    if (this.tab == "path") {
      this.mapCenterCoords = this.map.getCameraTarget();
      this.addressService.setCoords(this.mapCenterCoords);
    }
  }
```

Here's how the service `AddressService` works:

```
  private addressSetSource = new Subject<string>();

  addressSet$ = this.addressSetSource.asObservable();

  setCoords(coords: ILatLng) {
    this.geocoder
      .reverseGeocode(coords.lat, coords.lng, this.options)
      .then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
        let address =
          result[0]["subThoroughfare"] +
          ", " +
          result[0]["thoroughfare"] +
          ", " +
          result[0]["locality"];
        this.addressSetSource.next(address);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.addressSetSource.next("Error");
      });
  }
```

And finally here's my simplified `Header` component:

```
  start_address: string;
  end_address: string;

  constructor(private addressService: AddressService) {
    addressService.addressSet$.subscribe(this.onAddressChanged.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.start_time = "Hello World" // this shows up
  }

  onAddressChanged = (address: any): void => {
    console.log("Setting start address to: " + address);
    this.start_address = address;
    console.log("Test: " + this.start_address); // this works too
  };
```

And my `Header` component template:

```
<ion-item color="primary">
  <ion-icon name="arrow-back" (click)="back()"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
<ion-grid id="path-grid" color="primary">
  <ion-item color="primary">
    <ion-col size="2" align-self-center>
      <ion-label color="light">Start</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="10">
      <ion-input
        class="padding-input"
        [(ngModel)]="this.start_address" <!-- HERE -->
      ></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item color="primary">
    <ion-col size="2" align-self-center>
      <ion-label color="light">End</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="10">
      <ion-input class="padding-input">{{ this.end_address }}</ion-input>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-item>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

After searching for hours, it seems that Ionic4 still have this kind of little problems so far...
I ended up using NgZone which was recommended for Ionic 3 but not for Ionic 4.

```
constructor(private addressService: AddressService,
  private zone: NgZone) {
  addressService.addressSet$.subscribe(this.onAddressChanged.bind(this));
}

onAddressChanged = (address: any): void => {
    console.log("Setting start address to: " + address);
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.start_address = address;
    });
    console.log("Test: " + this.start_address); // this works too
  };
```